# Edit row data angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi i want to set the name of file  pdf to display in component angular 5 i  create a variable url

```
        url: '/assets/' + this.file.ileName +  '.pdf#page=',
```

but always return in error

Answer (score 0):

Use **=** instead of **:**

```
 url = '/assets/' + this.file.ileName +  '.pdf#page=';
```